# Calling onload function on specific page instead of all the pages where partial file is included

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ejs

I have included body tag in header partial file in ejs along with onload function. But want to call onload function on specific page instead of all the pages where partial file is included.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider taking/re-taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). This will help you better understand how to phrase your question so that we are better equipped to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(window.location.href == 'www.example.com'){//the function you want to make or the onload event}
```